# Create bar graphs with standard error bars for all columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to have code that will read through a dataset and create a bar graph with standard error bars for each variable by group.  Groups are specified in their own column and each variable that I'd like graphed is a column.  I think the main problem is passing a dynamic variable inside the for loop? I've used Iris as an example.  It crashes in summarise trying to calculate mean.

```
vars <- colnames(iris)

for (i in 1:length(vars)) {
   data <- na.omit(iris[, c("Species", vars[i])])

   graph_data <- data %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(
      n=n(),
      mean = mean([i]),
      sd=sd([i])
    ) %>%
    mutate( se=sd/sqrt(n))
  
  ggplot(graph_data) +
    geom_bar( aes(x=Species, y=mean), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
    geom_errorbar( aes(x=Species, ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), width=0.4, alpha=0.9, size=1.5)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. You could loop directly over the variable names, but make sure to exclude `Species`
2. Inside `summarise` you could access columns by names provided as characters by making use of the `.data` pronoun.
3. Finally to plot inside the `for` loop you have to call `print` or `plot`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

vars <- colnames(iris)

for (i in setdiff(vars, "Species")) {
  data <- na.omit(iris[, c("Species", i)])

  graph_data <- data %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(
      n = n(),
      mean = mean(.data[[i]]),
      sd = sd(.data[[i]])
    ) %>%
    mutate(se = sd / sqrt(n))

  p <- ggplot(graph_data) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = Species, y = mean), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(x = Species, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = 0.4, alpha = 0.9, size = 1.5) +
    labs(title = i)

  plot(p)
}
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without looping and using `facet_wrap` and a bit of data manipulation:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tidyr::drop_na(datasets::iris, Species) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  # get mean and se for all numeric variables
  dplyr::summarize_if(is.numeric, 
                      list(mean = ~mean(.),
                           se = ~ sd(.) / sqrt(length(.)))) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  # pivot columns to rows, excluding first column (Species)
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -1, 
                      names_to = c("variable", ".value"),
                      names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)$")

head(data)
 Species    variable      mean     se
  <fct>      <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>
1 setosa     Sepal.Length 5.01  0.0498
2 setosa     Sepal.Width  3.43  0.0536
3 setosa     Petal.Length 1.46  0.0246
4 setosa     Petal.Width  0.246 0.0149
5 versicolor Sepal.Length 5.94  0.0730
6 versicolor Sepal.Width  2.77  0.0444

ggplot2::ggplot(data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Species, y = mean), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Species, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = 0.4, alpha = 0.9, size = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ variable, scale = "free_y")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could loop through the values of `variable` in `data` above to create separate plots:

```
for (i in unique(data$variable)){
  graph_data <- dplyr::filter(data, variable == i)
  
  p <- ggplot2::ggplot(graph_data) + # note change to graph_data 
    geom_bar(aes(x = Species, y = mean), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(x = Species, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = 0.4, alpha = 0.9, size = 1.5)
  
  plot(p)
}
```